# Python MemoryError when storing saved lists

Tags: python, parsing, bioinformatics

I am new to python, so I apologize if this example is trivial.

I am trying to write a simple script that will pase and extract parts of two large datafiles (~40gb each) into one resulting file with a slightly altered format. I originally tried to use readlines(), but that reads all of the files into memory, and our instance only has 28gb of memory. Using the sizehint parameter only parses a portion of the file.

I am now iterating over the file. The problem is that I store the output of the text parsing in three lists that  grow to be rather large, eclipsing the available memory. I thought this would just switch to using the swap, which would be fine, but it instead just exits with a "MemoryError".

This works fine with small sample files, but chokes on our actual data.

The script:

```
import sys

a = []
b = []
c = []

file1 = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
for line in file1:
    if '@' in line:
        a.append(line.lstrip('@').rstrip('\n'))
        b.append(file1.next().rstrip('\n'))
file1.close()

file2 = open(sys.argv[2],"r")
for line in file2:
    if '@' in line: 
        c.append(file2.next().rstrip('\n'))
file2.close()

file3 = open(sys.argv[3],"w")
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    file3.write("".join([">",a[i],'\n',b[i],":",c[i],"\n"]))
```

What I have found online suggests creating some sort of database to store the variables, but that shouldn't be required. Do you have any ideas how I should deal with this?

For completeness, this is what I'm trying to do (from our example test-data:

```
file1: 

@Read.Salmonella_paratyphi_A_chromosome.29004.4835/1
TCGTGTACAGCATTCTTTATAGTGGAACGGTGACCGTACCGCAAAGCTGCGAAATCAACGCCGGACKIPPTCGTAG
+
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

file2:

@Read.Salmonella_paratyphi_A_chromosome.29004.4835/1
TCGTGTACAGCATTCTTTATAGTGGAACGGTGACCGTACCGCAAAGCTGCGAAATCAACGCCGGACAAACGATTCT
+
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

file3 (output):

>Read.Salmonella_paratyphi_A_chromosome.29004.4835/1
TCGTGTACAGCATTCTTTATAGTGGAACGGTGACCGTACCGCAAAGCTGCGAAATCAACGCCGGACKIPPTCGTAG:TCGTGTACAGCATTCTTTATAGTGGAACGGTGACCGTACCGCAAAGCTGCGAAATCAACGCCGGACAAACGATTCT
```

Comment: A database solution would make the most sense, because you are just using too much memory. It may get pushed to swap, but you cannot rely on this behavior. Storing intermediary results into a file on disk as you go along will be a much more efficient use of space rather than trying to get everything in ram.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about trying to do that, but wouldn't I run into the same memory error when I had the three resulting lists and then had to concatenate them?

Comment: List b is output from the first file, and list c is output from the second file. They are getting data from the same place, in either file, but the data is different. Edit: Oh, I made a typo. They are coming from different sys.argv[x] inputs. Fixed it now.

Comment: @Kipp: I am also from the bio field (migrating to programming). Looks like you're working with scientifical research. Go on with Python, study it a bit (or a lot), and you'll certainly won't regret, since its power and flexibility helps a lot with this kind of work.

Comment: @heltonbiker: Thanks for the advice! I am liking python better than perl, which is what it seems like most people are using for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Just so you know, there's a lot of bio work already done for you in the [BioPython suite](http://biopython.org/wiki/Biopython) - hopefully you're not reinventing the wheel

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo: This is a non-standard format for paired sequences, BioPython won't convert from fastq to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but it seems like the following should work:

```
file1 = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
file2 = open(sys.argv[2],"r")
file3 = open(sys.argv[3],"w")

for line1 in file1:
    if '@' in line1:  # line1.startswith('@') is probably better here
        a=line1.lstrip('@').rstrip('\n')
        b=file1.next().rstrip('\n')
        for line2 in file2:
            if '@' in line2:
                c=file2.next().rstrip('\n')
                break
        file3.write(">%s\n%s:%s\n"%(a,b,c))

file1.close()
file2.close()
file3.close()
```

In this case, you're only keeping one line in memory at a time for each file...which should be fine unless the files have *really long lines* ;^).

Also, since you're `lstrip`ing the '@' character, you might want to consider using `if line.startswith('@')` instead of `if '@' in line`.

Comment: I think the `for` loops shouldn't be nested, should they?

Comment: @heltonbiker -- They need to be nested because for the corresponding pair of lines (a,b) in file 1, there needs to be 1 line (c) in file2.  We search until we find that line and then break from the (inner) `for` loop.  The file object should remember it's position and restart the iteration from where we left off the next time through the loop (although, as I said, I haven't tried it myself ;))

Comment: It's possible, but I'm confused too ;o) Anyway, if the second for loop is someway "wrong", calling `next()` on file2 from inside the first `for` loop should keep the lines in proper order.

Comment: I think this has a slight indentation problem: the second loop still acts even if '@' wasn't in `line1`, and it writes a line to `file3` for each line in `line1`.

Comment: @DSM -- You're correct.  Sorry about my delay -- Internet cut out.

Comment: @heltonbiker -- Sorry, there was an indentation error on my part.  I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the files into the arrays (`a`, `b` and `c`), can you write into the file as you parse the files?

Something like this pseudo'ish code:

```
def get_line_with_at(a):
     while a:
         line = a.readline()
         if "@" in line:
             return line.strip()


# Open all file handles
a, b, c = [open(sys.argv[x + 1]) for x in range(3)]
out = open(sys.argv[4])

while a and b and c:
    # Repeat until a, b, and file handles are exhausted
    chunk1 = get_line_with_at(a)
    chunk2 = b.next().strip()
    chunk3 = get_line_with_at(c)

     out.write(
         ">%s\n%s:%s\n" % (chunk1, chunk2, chunk3))
```

That way you should only have to load very little into memory (theoretically 4 file handles and the contents of the current lines)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my [second, more compact] effort:

```
import sys
import itertools

def reader(fileobj, yield_at_line=False):
    for line in fileobj:
        if line.startswith('@'):
            at_line = line.lstrip('@').rstrip('\n')
            next_line = fileobj.next().rstrip('\n')
            yield (at_line, next_line) if yield_at_line else next_line

with open(sys.argv[1]) as file1, open(sys.argv[2]) as file2, open(sys.argv[3], "w") as file3:
    first = reader(file1, yield_at_line=True)
    second = reader(file2)
    for (a,b), c in itertools.izip(first, second):
        file3.write('>{}\n{}:{}\n'.format(a, b, c))
```

which gives

```
~/coding$ cat file1
@Read.Salmonella_paratyphi_A_chromosome.29004.4835/1
TCGTGTACAGCATTCTTTATAGTGGAACGGTGACCGTACCGCAAAGCTGCGAAATCAACGCCGGACKIPPTCGTAG
+
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

~/coding$ cat file2
@Read.Salmonella_paratyphi_A_chromosome.29004.4835/1
TCGTGTACAGCATTCTTTATAGTGGAACGGTGACCGTACCGCAAAGCTGCGAAATCAACGCCGGACAAACGATTCT
+
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

~/coding$ python simulwork.py file1 file2 file3
~/coding$ cat file3
>Read.Salmonella_paratyphi_A_chromosome.29004.4835/1
TCGTGTACAGCATTCTTTATAGTGGAACGGTGACCGTACCGCAAAGCTGCGAAATCAACGCCGGACKIPPTCGTAG:TCGTGTACAGCATTCTTTATAGTGGAACGGTGACCGTACCGCAAAGCTGCGAAATCAACGCCGGACAAACGATTCT
```